# Matching fields in different tables in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm

I have got two Django models that are completely unrelated to each other. Something like this:

```
class OldModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class NewModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Both of them contain a great number of records. I want to filter out only those records from `NewModel` whose name is equal to some record in the `OldModel`. What is the fastest and most efficient way to do this using Django ORM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new_models = NewModel.objects.filter(
     name__in=OldModel.objects.all().values_list('name', flat=True)
)`

This will cause folded select query to the database. To see the raw sql query just type `print new_models.query`.

Comment: This seems to be the most efficient method to do so. Now, I was wondering how can I print names from both the models for the same query?

Answer (score 1):

I can think only about `name__in` lookup called with flat values list.

```
old_models = OldModel.objects.all()
old_model_names = old_models.values_list('name', flat=True)
new_models = NewModel.objects.filter(name__in=old_model_names)
```

This should be converted into SQL query like this one

```
SELECT * FROM newmodel WHERE name in (SELECT name from oldmodel);
```

Also You can consider `extra` statement which allow to create optimized version of query

Please see documentation here

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra

You should use `where / tables` part of it. But this is nor raw Django ORM indeed.

For more accurate SQL query use information from `OldModel._meta` and `NewModel._meta` this will allow you to not hardcode fields and tables names.

Comment: Can't there be a more efficient way? Because `old_models = OldModel.objects.all()` will bring everything to a halt as it evaluates to: `SELECT * FROM old_models`. This is something that I want to avoid.

Comment: That's not what will happen, because querysets are lazy. They are only evaluated (executed against the database), when needed. The queryset will be evaluated in the `filter`, where it will be executed as "SELECT name FROM ..."

Comment: But `old_model_names = old_models.values_list('name', flat=True)` will cause the query to execute, isn't it? This would evaluate to a `SELECT * FROM table_name`, right?

Comment: That's not what will happen, because querysets are lazy. ’Can't there be a more efficient way?’ second one with `extra` is more efficient